# Search for a string pattern (regex) inside of files

Tags: shell, unix

How can I search for a particular string inside of all files inside under a given particular directory recursively.

For example, I want to search for the text:

```
<a title="Hot or Not" href="http://aaaaat"><span>Hot or Not</span></a>
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Seems like a pretty good question to me.

Answer (score 5):

`$ grep -lR 'Hot or Not this is my word that i want to search' ./somedir/` ?

`-l` suppresses normal output; instead prints the name of each input file from  which  output would normally have been printed. `-R` or `-r` reads all files under each directory, recursively.

Comment: will this return filename which contains the pattern?

Comment: @algorithmX: yes - that's what the -l does (note it is an 'ell' rather than a one)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is 'grep'.  Try man grep at terminal.

I assume you're using Linux?

Comment: yes i know that i can use grp , but whats the syntax i want to get the name of the file which contains the given pattern

Comment: I think something like:

grep -w 'Hot|or|Not' /directory/to/be/searched

Again, I did say to consult the man pages

Also, an excellent tutorial can be located here:

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_02.html